# how to use embedded tomcat thread pool

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have simple web application with spring boot. i want to use embedded tomcat thread pool to process some request simultaneously.

Is there any way to get common thread pool of embedded tomcat?

Comment: Request are already handled concurrently...

Comment: @M.Deinum i want some other logic to execute with thread pool

Comment: That is not what your question is about, also don't use the request handling pool for other things.

Comment: i want to use server.tomcat.max-threads=200 threads (worker threads) instead to create custom thread pool

Comment: Don't. That thread pool is specifically for handling requests. If you start using that for different things, your server might become unresponsive. Use a dedicated thread pool for that. That is why Spring Boot also has a `TaskExecutor` configured (if you are on 2.1 that is).